Pandas read tab separated csv
I have a problem with plotting my load profiles for my Bachelor thesis.
I've got a csv file, which is separated by tabs, like this:
PV-Energie (AC) abzgl. Standby-Verbrauch,
-0,01747
-0,01747
-0,01747
-0,01747
-0,01747
-0,01747
-0,01747
-0,05512
0,1418
72,219
87,723
89,751
41,49
33,484
27,917
3,5819
-0,05512
-0,01747
-0,01747
-0,01747
-0,01747
-0,01747
-0,01747
-0,01747
-0,01747

Is it possible to choose "tab" as a separator?
Here is my code:
from oemof import solph
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from oemof.tools import economics
import numpy as np
from oemof.tools import logger

logger.define_logging()

logger.info('Programm gestartet')

filename = 'PV.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename)

logger.info('Datei wurde eingelesen')

ax = df.plot.area(subplots=True, figsize=(10,7))

ax[0].set_ylabel("Leistung in kW")
ax[0].set_xlabel("Zeit in h")

plt.title('power demand')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
logger.info('Programm beendet')

I would like to find a solution for my problem.

check this code snippet,
import pandas as pd

#read the csv file into a pandas dataframe, sep flag set to \t
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', sep='\t')

print(df)


Copying and pasting the example you provided it seems not to be tab separated. I suggest to use a text editor like Notepad++ to replace the spaces with tab (\t). In this way I've obtained the following:
PV-Energie  (AC) abzgl. Standby-Verbrauch,
-0,01747     -0,01747    -0,01747
-0,01747     -0,01747    -0,01747
-0,01747     -0,05512    0,1418
72,219  87,723  89,751
41,49   33,484  27,917
3,5819  -0,05512     -0,01747
-0,01747     -0,01747    -0,01747
-0,01747     -0,01747    -0,01747

Then I've read the csv with the tab as separator:
df = pd.read_csv(
    r"C:\Users\tab_separated.csv",
    sep=r'\t'
)

Obtaining the following:
|    | PV-Energie   | (AC) abzgl.   | Standby-Verbrauch,   |
|---:|:-------------|:--------------|:---------------------|
|  0 | -0,01747     | -0,01747      | -0,01747             |
|  1 | -0,01747     | -0,01747      | -0,01747             |
|  2 | -0,01747     | -0,05512      | 0,1418               |
|  3 | 72,219       | 87,723        | 89,751               |
|  4 | 41,49        | 33,484        | 27,917               |
|  5 | 3,5819       | -0,05512      | -0,01747             |
|  6 | -0,01747     | -0,01747      | -0,01747             |
|  7 | -0,01747     | -0,01747      | -0,01747             |

